# Checking continuity looking whether image set is interval or not

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $A(\neq \phi)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f : A \to \mathbb{R}$ is a monotone function such that the image $f (A)$ is an interval. Then prove that $f$ is a continuous function.

And if $f(A)$ is an interval can we find some other condition on $f$ which makes it continuous? (because $f(A)$ interval and $f$ continuous does not imply function is monotonic as much as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_0 $ be arbitrary chosen from $A$
Without loss of generality assssume $A=[a,b]$(check that)

By monotonicty of $f$ (assume to be increasing)

sup $_{a\leq x<x_0}f(x)=f(x_0^-)\leq f(x_0)\leq f(x_0^+)=inf _{x_0<x\leq b}f(x)$

If $f(x_0^+)>f(x_0)$;

From the last inequality,there exists a strictly decreasing sequence $x_n$ in $  (x_0,b]$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x_0^+)$ so $f(x_n)>f(x_0^+)>f(x_0)$
Since $f(A)$ is an interval so there exists $x^{'}$ such that $f(x^{'})=f(x_0^+)$.

Again $f(x^{'})$=inf$_{x_0<x\leq b}f(x) \leq$  inf$_{x_0<x\leq x^{'}}f(x)$ since $(x_0,x^{'}]\subseteq (x_0,b]$

Also by monotinicity of $f$  inf$_{x_0<x\leq x^{'}}f(x)$

Thus $f(x_0^+)=f(x_0)$;

similarly prove $f(x_0^-)=f(x_0)$;